# Double clicking a resource in Eclipse Project Explorer does not open the second file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In an Eclipse based application (RCP), when double clicking on a file that appears in the project explorer, for the first file this will work – the associated editor will open. However, when double clicking again on a file, it will not open. If you click somewhere out of the Project Explorer and then return to the Project Explorer, then the second double click will work.

Note that right-clicking on the resource and selecting “Open” always works. In addition, in Package Explorer it always works.

I believe this is related to eclipse bugs [285239](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285239) and [256761](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=256761).

Does anyone know of a way that I can overcome this problem, as the RCP developer. The file editor is a custom editor in one of my plugins.

The problem does not seem to happen to me with java files in standard eclipse for java development.

Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by implementing a `setFocus` method on the editor class. In the `setFocus`, I set the focus to some component. (To be precise in my case the editor was a subclass of `SharedHeaderFormEditor` so I set the focus to the active page).

The truth is that the specification of the `setFocus` method in `IWorkbenchPart` requires you to "assign the focus to one of the controls contained in the part's parent composite". It seems that the default implementation of setFocus in some cases did not do that (I don't know why, maybe I was missing something or for other reason).

Note that also setting focus explicitly to a control from within editor initializing partialy solves the problem.